# How to put a spinning fontawesome icon inside a link?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm using FontAwesome 3.1.0, and this simple code doesn't work as one would normally expect:

```
<a href="/">
    <!-- other html content -->
    <i class="icon-spinner icon-spin"></i>
</a>
```

Simply changing the `a` tag to `div` makes it work.

How to make the CSS3 animation work? Or is this not possible? I would rather **not** change it to `div` and make a link-like behavious via JS.

**UPDATE:**

The code above actually works, like on jsfiddle. It doesn't work on my page, though. There must be some underlying conflict that I can't figure out.

Example: http://www.iroquote.com/games/Udws8uZWCgAH6vfM/gta-5-gameplay-video-released

Try editing `a.post-agree-amount:first` where there is a `<i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i>`. When I change that to `<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin"></i>`, it doesn't animate. If you move this `<a>` around the DOM with the browser code inspector, it still doesn't animate. But once I change `<a>` to `<div>`, it animates.

I'm using Google Chrome 28.0, but also saw this behaviour in Firefox 22.0.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the problem and the solution.

**CSS3 animations apparently don't work with `display: inline` elements**, and Bootstrap's css had a rule that made `<i>` icon elements have `display: inline`. Except for `<i>` icon elements **inside** `a.btn`, Bootstrap's css had a rule to apply `display: inline-block` to them.

So all we need to do is apply `display: inline-block` to those `i.icon-spinner.icon-spin` inside the links.

(Thanks [Praveen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1671639/praveen) for useful comments)

Comment: That was really extremely helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YpCsx/3/).  But you should have the icons tag `<i>` outside the `anchor` tag, otherwise it will be hyper linked.

Change your like this

```
<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin"></i>
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YpCsx/2/)

Comment: @STALTZ not sure.  are you referring this http://s23.postimg.org/hoap78kq3/yep.png ? In chrome v28

Comment: Hi, I'm talking about the `<i>` tag **inside** the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Almost. That's the `a.post-agree`, I was referring to `a.post-agree-amount`